# Paypal checkout can't transfer the order details

Tags: html, paypal

The following Paypal payment form, inside an html file, can't transfer to my Paypal Business account the order details "Name", "Surname" and "Email". It worked correctly until last July.
How can I fix it?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myaddress@email.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="IT">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ITEM NAME">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="XX-YYzzz:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<table>
<tr align="center"><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="ITEM TYPE">SELECT ITEM TYPE</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0" value="" >

    <option value="Type1">Type1 10,25 EUR</option>
    
    <option value="Type2">Type2 20,25 EUR</option>
    
</select> </td></tr>
<tr align="center"><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Name"><br>Name</td></tr><tr align="center"><td><input type="text" value="" required="required" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
<tr align="center"><td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Surname">Surname</td></tr><tr align="center"><td><input type="text" value="" required="required" name="os2" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
<tr align="center"><td><input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Email">Email</td></tr><tr align="center"><td><input type="email" value="" required="required" name="os3" maxlength="200">
<br></td></tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Type1">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="10.25">

<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Type2">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="20.25">



<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="ITEM TYPE,Name,Surname,Email">


<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/IT/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - Il metodo rapido, affidabile e innovativo per pagare e farsi pagare.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I tried different lengths of order details but the problem didn't fix

Comment: Unless this is inside email, you should be aware that the `align` attribute has been obsolete for 20 years or more. Note that this is not a fix.